# WSO2 Business Activity Monitor cannot edit am_stats_analyzer

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am trying to fix the bug I am dealing with that is documented here https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2032

When I go into my BAM 2.4.1 admin console and go to "Home > Manage > Analytics > List" to try and make the change to my am_stats_analyzer script, I am unable to edit it (that option is not available).

Does anyone know another way to update this script so it no longer throws this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Editing the hive scripts which was deployed by any toolboxes are not recommended; since during the restart of the server OR any redeployment of the same toolbox, will cause loss of your local changes. Therefore the edit option of the hive script that was deployed via a toolbox was removed; if you further need to do the changes in hive scripts via BAM management console, then you need to click on Copy New Script, and do you changes there and save it with another name.

If you want to do the modifications to the same script that was deployed by APIM toolbox, then you need do the changes to the toolbox it self. Extract the toolbox, and Go to analytics directory and edit the hive script what you interested on, and then again zip it, and rename with .tbox extension. Now redeploy your updated toolbox in BAM.

Comment: I modified the am_stats_analyzer Hive script with the new code. The SQL statement actually looked the same as what replaced it. I replaced .tbox file and restarted BAM and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation} -  Failed to write data to database {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation}
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "CONSUMERKEY"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO API_Resource_USAGE_SUMMARY (method,resourcepath,version,consumerkey,time,hostname,context,day,year,month,apipublisher,total_request_count,api) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [90006-140]
 at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)

Comment: Do I need to drop and recreate the table as well?

Comment: You need to have COALESCE(consumerKey,'') instead of barely consumerkey to wherever you are trying to insert into the SQL table; hence please change the hive script accordingly, and then you won't see this error. Also Make sure your modified hive script successfully got updated and deployed with toolbox in BAM. (Go to Analutics -> List -> Copy as New script and check your changes are there in the script).

Comment: It looks like it's correct in BAM. Line 18 of the hive script " insert overwrite table APIRequestSummaryData select api, api_version,version, apiPublisher, COALESCE(consumerKey,'')"
Could something else be causing this?